# how to access variables from .pm file to an .pl file

Tags: perl

**`1.pm`**

```
package 1;
our $Var= "hello";
```

**`2.pl`**

```
use 1;
print "$Var\n";
```

am doing exactly what I am mentioned above in 2 files `1.pm` and `2.pl`.
in `2.pl` I am not able to access that variable `$Var`.

Please can you help me out?
How should I declare that variable in the `1.pm` file (the variable should be global)?

Thanks,

Comment: Don't use numbers as package names, and `print $mypackage::Var` http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#Packages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Summary: **package names cannot begin with a number**

Detailed description:

First of all always use

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

in your scripts. You would have noticed an error message:

```
Global symbol "$Var" requires explicit package name at 2.pl line 6.
Execution of 2.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

You can access it using the package name

```
$1::Var
```

**but** you will get

```
Bareword found where operator expected at 2.pl line 6, near "$1::Var"
    (Missing operator before ::Var?)
Bareword "::Var" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at 2.pl line 6.
Execution of 2.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Try using a module name not beginning with a number. E.g., `Mod.pm`

```
package Mod;

use strict;
use warnings;

our $Var= 'hello';
1;
```

and `2.pl`

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use Mod;

print $Mod::Var . "\n";

1;
```

From [perlmod](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#Packages)

> Only identifiers starting with letters (or underscore) are stored in a package's symbol table.

Although not mandatory it is customary (and strongly suggested) to capitalize package names. See for example [Perl::Critic::Policy::NamingConventions::Capitalization](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Perl-Critic/lib/Perl/Critic/Policy/NamingConventions/Capitalization.pm)

Comment: @JackXu Why? Running `perl 2.pl` gives me as expected `hello`

Comment: Name "Test::Var" used only once: possible typo at test_package.pl line 7.
Use of uninitialized value $Test::Var in print at test_package.pl line 7. I just replace the Mod to Test

Comment: You should open a different question and post both your files. Is pretty difficult to see what you did in a comment.

Comment: @JackXu `Test` is the name of a core perl module. You'd better choose a different name.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem has nothing to do with the file that the variable was declared in, but with the namespace you put it in using the `package` keyword. Also, make sure that your namespaces don't start with a number. From perlmod(1):

> Only identifiers starting with letters (or underscore) are
>   stored in a package's symbol table.